# How to use pid as key for log4j2 Kafka appender?

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j2

I am trying to send logs to Kafka and I would like to have the process id as the key for the log message.

I found that the `key` in Kafka appender supports lookups. But how can I use `pid` in the `key` field just as I have done in the PatternLayout.

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="my_log_topic" key="%processId">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %processId  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        <Property name="bootstrap.servers">127.0.0.1:9092</Property>
    </Kafka>
</Appenders>
```

Can we use patterns in the `key` field? Or is there any way to get the **PID in the lookup**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following line in `main()` worked fine.

`ProcessIdUtil` is found in `org.apache.logging.log4j.util` package.

```
System.setProperty("pid", ProcessIdUtil.getProcessId());
```

and then use `key="${sys:pid}"`

```
<Kafka name="Kafka" topic="my_log_topic" key="${sys:pid}">
    <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %processId  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
    <Property name="bootstrap.servers">127.0.0.1:9092</Property>
</Kafka>
```

*Is there a better way, without changing the code?*